# How to Send formData through Axios in Vue JS and Node JS?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, axios

> Api.Js -->
>   This is Connector of Api (Node Js)

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:4040",
        credentials: true
        //WithCredential: true
        //WithCredentials : true
    })
}
```

> PageService.js

```
import Api from "@/services/Api";

export default{
    threadSubmit(params) {
        return Api().post("page/threadSubmit", params);
    },
    // threadSubmit(params) {
    //     return Api().post("page/threadSubmit", params, {
    //         headers: {
    //             'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    //         }
    //     });
    // }
}
```

> Page.vue

```
<script>
   import PageService from "@/services/PageService";
   export default{
      methods:{
         async feedFinalSubmit(){
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("files", this.file);
            formData.append("description", this.thread.description);
            formData.append("pageID", this.$route.params.id);

            const response = await PageService.threadSubmit({
               pageID: this.$route.params.id,
               description: this.thread.description,
               files: formData
            });
            if (response.data.success){
               //do somethnig
            }
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```

Problem is that, In every request #FormData send empty result.
What should i do to send multipart form data using that Api.js file ?
Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: "http://localhost:4040",
        credentials: true,
        headers :{
           'Content-Type': undefined
        }
        //WithCredential: true
        //WithCredentials : true
    })
}


 async feedFinalSubmit(){
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append("files", this.file);
            formData.append("description", this.thread.description);
            formData.append("pageID", this.$route.params.id);

            const dict = {};
            dict['pageID']=this.$route.params.id;
            dict['description']=this.thread.description;

            const blob = new Blob([dict], {
                        type: 'application/json'
                        });
            formData.append("JsonData", blob); 
            const response = await PageService.threadSubmit(formData);
            if (response.data.success){
               //do somethnig
            }
         }
```

Comment: Because of headers:{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'} my others input objects are not submitted as well.

Comment: Other way is to send json data with FormData.
const blob = new Blob([json], {
  type: 'application/json'
});
const data = new FormData();
data.append("document", blob);
Then just pass the data in your method.